# emacs term kill word strange behavior

Tags: emacs

I have noticed strange behavior when using term-mode

if I kill word in termmode using shell shortcuts (Alt-d), word disappears, but actually does not get killed.
Here is an example

```
andrey@localhost:~ yes no-such-file
# press Alt-d
andrey@localhost:~ no-such-file
no-such-file
no-such-file
no-such-file
```

rather than

```
andrey@localhost:~ no-such-file
bash: no-such-file: command not found
```

thank you

Comment: It Work For Me™, so you should provide more details: your version of Emacs, your OS, whether you have the same problem without your `.emacs` (start Emacs with `emacs -q`), whether you have the same problem without your `.bashrc`, and anything else you think may be relevant. Other things that might also help: what does `echo $TERM` show, and what happens if you press Ctrl+L right after Alt+D?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior you're experiencing is the key stroke being mapped to an emacs function that acts on the buffer, rather than getting passed to the shell. You should confirm that by doing `C-h k Alt-d` and seeing if it reports the mapping as `kill-word`.

If there are keys you want to pass to the shell rather than letting emacs (term-mode) take them, add a function to the `term-mode-hook` including something like

`(define-key term-raw-map [(meta ?d)] 'term-send-raw)`

to send the raw keystroke on.

An option to remember is switching between `term-line-mode` and `term-char-mode`.